# Arbitrary install a .jar file using a regex

Tags: java, bash

So I was wondering in bash is there a way to install a jar file like this:

```
java -jar /opt/install.*.jar
```

I will only have one .jar file in the /opt directory with the start of the name called install followed by some versioning e.g install6.5.3.jar.

Is there a way to do this or would i have to do an ls .jar and extract the name that way?

Comment: Do you need run one JAR file or many JAR files? You should make your question clearly.

Comment: @DoNhuVy "I will only have one .jar file in the /opt directory". Pretty clear to me.

Comment: `cd /opt` then `java -jar *.jar`.

Comment: Although I am only executing one jar in /opt I can't guarantee that there are other jars in that folder. The only thing I can guarantee is there will be one jar file which starts with Install<version>.jar  which I will be running, what would you say advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash would automatically expand that `*`, assuming you've not disabled globbing.

For example, if you've got a directory like:

```
mkdir /tmp/foo
touch /tmp/foo/bar.jar
```

and you executed

```
java /tmp/foo/*.jar
```

then bash would execute:

```
java /tmp/foo/bar.jar
```

So you don't have to do anything special.

Comment: Although I am only executing one jar in /opt I can't guarantee that there are other jars in that folder. The only thing I can guarantee is there will be one jar file which starts with Install<version>.jar  which I will be running, what would you say advise?

Comment: Use `install*.jar` instead of `*.jar`.

Comment: Brilliant, that works ahah, was thinking too much in regex before using .* after install instead of just the  *. Thanks :D